# ngRouter to ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

I recently purchased an **angularjs** template which i am using to build my application, however i noticed that **ngRouter** was used instead of **ui-router** which i prefer and am more familiar with.

I tried  including **ui-router** and changing all the routes and it worked, however there was some extra code in my routes that i still do not understand and do not know where to put, this is the old route for my dashboard:

```
$routeProvider.when("/dashboard", {
    templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
    resolve: {
        deps: ["$ocLazyLoad", function(a) {
            return a.load([jqload.c3, jqload.sparkline])
            .then(function() {
                return a.load({
                    name: "app.directives",
                    files: ["scripts/lazyload/directives/sparkline.directive.js"]
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("angular-c3");
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("easypiechart");
            })

        }]
    }
});
```

This is what i changed it to:

```
.state('admin.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: '/_admin/views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is a great portion of code missing which affects certain functionality of my dashboard.  My question is using **ui-router** where do i place all the code in **resolve**:

```
resolve: {
        deps: ["$ocLazyLoad", function(a) {
            return a.load([jqload.c3, jqload.sparkline])
            .then(function() {
                return a.load({
                    name: "app.directives",
                    files: ["scripts/lazyload/directives/sparkline.directive.js"]
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("angular-c3");
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("easypiechart");
            })

        }]
    }
```

I've never come across **resolve** before, i am quite new to **angularjs** and dunno what to do about this section after switching to **ui-router**.

Comment: ui-router has resolve also, see docs

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve, actually just copy same section, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolve property essentially tells angularjs that the callbacks within it must complete before the state is displayed. NgRouter has this, but so does ui-router. [Here's some reading for you.](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)

This code should work:

```
.state('admin.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: '/_admin/views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        deps: ["$ocLazyLoad", function(a) {
            return a.load([jqload.c3, jqload.sparkline])
            .then(function() {
                return a.load({
                    name: "app.directives",
                    files: ["scripts/lazyload/directives/sparkline.directive.js"]
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("angular-c3");
            })
            .then(function() {
                return a.load("easypiechart");
            })

        }]
    }
})
```